# please explain? api signature example

Tags: api, oauth, signature, hmac, sha512

*(Update: still stuck after changes made from John's comment)*
I am hoping for somebody to kindly try to explain in layman's terms how the signature is generated in the following example? I am pretty much stuck at this point.. I get the same result in an online hash generator (see picture below) and in my own code; but it differs from the example in the website (also pictured below).

https://www.gate.io/docs/apiv4/en/#authentication
*edit: website seems only reachable through google search,  direct link gives 404? So I attached the page as image, see below*

Request: List all orders

> GET /api/v4/futures/orders?contract=BTC_USD&status=finished&limit=50
> HTTP/1.1

secret:

> secret

resulting signature string *(edit: updated, thanks @John Glenn)*：

> GET\n/api/v4/futures/orders\ncontract=BTC_USD&status=finished&limit=50\ncf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e\n1541993715

(note that in the example on the website, there are line breaks for readability)

Signature generated according to the example:

> eae42da914a590ddf727473aff25fc87d50b64783941061f47a3fdb92742541fc4c2c14017581b4199a1418d54471c269c03a38d788d802e2c306c37636389f0

Explanation from the website:

> Signature generation method is HexEncode(HMAC_SHA512(secret,
> signature_string)), i.e., the hexadecimal digest output of HMAC-SHA512
> with APIv4 secret as secret and signature string as message.

But if I put it into a HMAC-SHA512 generator (e.g., https://www.javainuse.com/hmac), the value I get is:

> 58000238bf5eef226028e108df259184f14bf3021eb27c324a808334d187da42c38f4510b30215ee9b0c05d6352396e99f67fa920079746bb4dfd70506592f6d

I suspect I am missing a very essential point but I am quite lost at this time..
thank you very much for your help!

[image]

[image]

[image: hash result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The "\n" were not regular expressions but actual newlines in the example. In other words, the newlines should be entered as ascii newline character.
Then I got the same result in the generator as from the website.
[image: correct result]

Answer (score 1):

Your resulting signature string is incorrect. According the to website, this is how you should build it, with each element separated by `\n`.

- request verb
- request URL
- plain text query string from the URL
- hash of the request body, which is an empty string in this case
- the Unix timestamp in seconds

For your example, the resulting signature string values should be:

- GET (but you have POST)
- /api/v4/futures/orders
- contract=BTC_USD&status=finished&limit=50 (MISSING from your string)
- *just use the empty string hash value from the example*
- *use the Unix timestamp from the example*

Comment: Unfortunately, after the correction (sorry a copy paste error!), the problem still remains...
Thank you for taking the time to look into this! I would be very thankful if you could have another look, I'm really stuck atm, also I cant find any other examples online..

Comment: @Rusty75 I don't see the signature generated in their documentation anymore. Perhaps they made a mistake calculating it and just removed it altogether.

Comment: update: fixed! It was the newline characters. Thanks for the help!